# Click on button scroll div down(upto bottom) in angular 6?

Tags: angular, scroll

I refer this link (NPM: @nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to) and so many answers but i not got perfect solution. when i click on button my div page(div height is not fixed it may very) it is scrolls down little bit only,but I want make page scrolls down upto bottom in angular 6. any other solutions or modification appritiated. Thank you

chat.component.html

```
<div id="destination"> My Content is here</div>
<button (click)="getChatMessages()">SAVE</button>
```

chat.component.ts

```
import { ScrollToService, ScrollToConfigOptions } from '@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to';

constructor(private _scrollToService: ScrollToService) { }

getChatMessages(){
  const config: ScrollToConfigOptions = {
    target: 'destination'
  };
  this._scrollToService.scrollTo(config);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div> My Content is here <div id="destination"></div></div>` 
make a small div in last, before close your div. [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-kugax8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Asanka this not works i make <div id="destination"></div> before closing div

Comment: do you remove id="destination" from parent div?

Comment: yes i remove from parent div it now scrolls little more but not scrolls upto bottom

Comment: Ok. what you want to is put this - > <div id="destination"></div> in your page where you want to scrolls.

Comment: I have put example you can see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181660/discussion-between-asanka-and-john).

Answer (score 2):

Tried a lot on this. No any library helped in my situation.

So you may try what i use ;

```
_onButtonClick (e) {

        this._pageY = e.pageY;

        if (true) {
          //scroll while drag
          const y = this._pageY;
          const container =  <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.yourcontainerclass');
          const containerBottom =  container.offsetTop + container.offsetHeight;
          const containerTop =  container.offsetTop;
          if (containerBottom - y < 120) { // To leave a space and scroll down
            container.scrollTop += containerBottom - 30;
          } else if (containerTop + y < 250) { // you do not need this but if you have a button on top,you may want to scroll up

            container.scrollTop -= containerTop + 30;
          }
        }
      }
```

Add this on your button like `onclick = _onButtonClick($event)`

Comment: you may find the definition here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsettop.asp . If it gives an error, check your htmlelement if you took the correct one from the dom

Comment: @user10411207
if you replace '.yourcontainerclass' by a real selector, you will get rid of thatoffsetTop error.